# unexpected EOF while parsing (summing up)

Tags: python

```
a = eval(input())
b = "."
p = 0
contador = 0
while a != b:
    a = eval(input())
    contador = contador + 1
    if a == b:
     print(contador)
     print(p+a)
```

I want a program that reads a number line by line that sums up how many numbers I wrote (contador) and sums up the numbers between them. When writing the numbers after writing "." the program would stop and do both of those prints. And I'm getting this errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `eval()` is the problem. This will work:

```
a = input()
b = "."
p = 0
contador = 0
while a != b:
    contador = contador + 1
    p += int(a)

    a = input()
    if a == b:
        print(contador)
        print(p)
```

You use `eval()` when you want to turn a string into python executable code. For example doing `eval('print("hello")')` would print hello.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved the error but if i run it, it won't sum up the numbers between them it's returning 0. Is there another mistake? I tried p = p + a and then it gives me the same error of int + str

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! Can you explain your logic behind the changes you made?

Comment: when you tried `p = p + a` it wasn't working since `a` is a string so you need to do `int(a)` to turn it into an integer.